# can we add a PHP code inside a CGI script in C?

Tags: php, c, cgi

I am trying to add a small piece of PHP code in my CGI program (using C) for my web application in a similar way one adds the html code in the C program using simple `printf`.

This is what I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{

    printf("%s%c%c\n", "Content-Type:php;charset=iso-8859-1",13,10);
    printf("<?php echo 'hiii';?>");
    return(0);
}
```

But when I try to run this in Apache, it is not displaying anything. What might be the issue? Is PHP is not allowed inside a CGI script? Is there any other way in C?

Comment: **(a)** php code printed as a string is just that - there's nothing in your code to check that it's php code and invoke the php interpreter - your output goes directly to the browser. **(b)** Nope, you can't do this. **(c)** For this example, clearly `printf('hiii');` is the way. - cant really give you a more general answer, though if it's a CGI, you should implement the functionality in the same lang as the rest of the cgi. **(d)** The end of the http header should be \r\n\r\n - you're outputting \r\n\r (13,10,'\n'). Make it `printf("%s\r\n\r\n", "Content-Type:php;charset=iso-8859-1");`

Comment: No, there's no way that would work: what you print gets sent back directly to the browser. I suggest you rethink your design.

Comment: @enhzflep  I changed the header , but is giving me the same result

Comment: @user2723949 - I overlooked something before - you seem to have the wrong content-type set. You've got content-type set to php - change it to text. Sorry for the formatting, this code does work - tried it a minute ago: `#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s\r\n\r\n", "Content-Type:text;charset=iso-8859-1");
    printf("hiii");
    return(0);
}`

Comment: @enhzflep   I actually have more php code which I planned to do like this.. My problem is , During the login process I am calling a CGI to validate the user and password of root , and If password is right I wanted to start a SESSION with the only user we have and will give a timeout of 100 seconds in each page , I know to work a little bit with sessions using php only ,Thats why I thought of giving them inside cgi. So is there any other way to achieve this..?

Comment: Apart from how Dennis replied to a very similar comment of yours, you could, I think, use PHP to request the CGI - with a url something like `localhost/cgi-bin/cgiName.exe`. If you use `file_get_contents` and specify the cgi file, you can then examine the contents of the response, before starting the SESSION if appropriate. You'd probably want to use the cgic library to retrieve and GET or POST variables passed to the CGI program. cgic library here: http://www.boutell.com/cgic/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all intents and purposes, PHP *is* a cgi-script in its own right. It then needs to be parsed and processed, for instance by apache or fastcgi.

If I understand what you're currently doing, you're trying to send a header (which should be separated from the body as appropriate, btw: `\r\n\r\n`), followed by a line of php.

But then, this `<?php … ?>` bit is sent *as is* to the browser. The latter assumes a content type of html from lack of knowing php. And since the stuff is enclosed within `<` and `>` the browser ignores it as an invalid tag — hence the blank page. If you view the source of your page you'll likely see the php code.

Comment: yes Sir, you are right ,, I am able to see the php code when I viewed the source. So No way ??  I actually have more php code which I planned to do like this.. My problem is , During the login process I am calling a CGI to validate the user and password of root , and If password is right I wanted to start a SESSION with the only user we have and will give a timeout of 100 seconds in each page , I know to work a little bit with sessions using php only ,Thats why I thought of giving them inside cgi. So is there any other way to achieve this..?

Comment: Tbh, I'm quite sure it's possible to think up *something*, perhaps by using the php libraries and so forth, but I don't have the beginning of a clue of how to interface a C cgi with php so can't help much beyond highlighting what seemed obviously wrong.